# XML DOM setNodeValue("") on a Text node, also removes its containing element's opening tag

Tags: java, xml, dom

The original xml element considered is something like this.

```
<Sender>name</Sender>
```

Calling

```
node.setNodeValue("");
```

on a node of type text removes the opening tag of its containing element resulting

```
</Sender>
```

When I call

```
node.setNodeValue("something");
```

then it works as expected.

```
<Sender>something</Sender>
```

Is there something wrong with this approach? What I want to do is to remove the text content.

```
<Sender></Sender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look again carefully what you get after calling

```
node.setNodeValue("");
```

I'm sure you got `<Sender/>`, but not `</Sender>`.

`<Sender/>` is an empty-element tag.
It is a short-hand defined to mean the same as `<Sender></Sender>`
(start-tag and end-tag with no content in between).
 .

See the [XML-specification (section 3.1)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-starttags) which says:

> The representation of an empty element is either a start-tag
>   immediately followed by an end-tag, or an empty-element tag.

So both are semantically equivalent, and hence there is no point
in wanting one instead of the other.

Comment: Of course! Thank you!. My ignorance, I did not know about that.